# To take screenshot and save it into sd card

Tags: java, android

Here I am trying to take a screenshot and also to save into sd card but I am failing while saving . please help me.

```
 public void onClick(View OnclickView) {
     boolean success = false;
     view = OnclickView.getRootView();
     view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
     ScreenShotHold.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 60, bytearrayoutputstream);
     File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
     File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "test.png");
     boolean success = false;
     // Encode the file as a PNG image.
     FileOutputStream outStream;
     try {
         outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bitmap " + bitmap, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "outstream " + outStream, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */
         outStream.flush();
         outStream.close();
         success = true;
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     if (success == true) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 }
```

Here I am getting failed result, but I am getting screenshot.

Comment: my understanding is that you have to have set permissions in manifest for sd card

Comment: Ya i have done that at first, but I am not getting.

Comment: on which android version you are trying this

Comment: I am trying in android studio.

Comment: U better check in android manifest

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` I have mentioned in android manifest

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Bitmap screenshotedBitmap = yourBitmap;
String lastInsertedPath =  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), screenshotedBitmap, "myImage", "modified image");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This works perfect, I got my answer.

 view = OnclickView.getRootView();

 view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

 bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
 count++;
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "count is "+count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
             if(count==1)
             {
                 bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                 ImagePath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                 getContentResolver(),
                 bitmap,
                 "demo_image",
                 "demo_image"
                 );

                 URI = Uri.parse(ImagePath);

                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```